# How expensive are React Native Views?

Tags: javascript, view, components, render

Deciding on whether I should use <View style={{marginBottom: 10}}/> or just marginBottom on the upper component. I feel that using Views makes for better readability & maintainability of code but I'm not sure what is common practice. How expensive are React Native Views with just 1 style property, computation & memory-wise?

Comment: You shouldn't worry too much about styling (especially when you're not working with animations) as they won't slow down your app. The main thing you should focus on (like for any software) is anything that will require a draw call. Changing something in the interface is what's costly. That's why your components should be optimized and only render what is required at the appropriate time.

Comment: @kemicofaghost With styling do you mean the marginBottom on e.g. a Button, or also a View with only marginBottom as property?